# How to manage HTML elements attributes, best practice

Tags: javascript, performance

What is the best way to set/get attributes in terms of performace:

```
var div = document.getElementById('someId');

//Setting Attributes
div.setAttribute('class', 'myClass');
div.attributes.class.value = 'myClass';
div.className = "myClass";

//Getting Attributes Values
console.log(div.getAttribute('class'));
console.log(div.attributes.class.value);
console.log(div.className);

//Checking Attribute Existance
if (div.attributes.hasOwnProperty('class')) ..;
if (!div.className) ..;
```

Also is using html5 dataset a good idea for setting custom `data-*` attributes? and do the values of such attributes have to be always a string or can i use other types of values like objects and arrays?

Comment: btw - you can also use `classList` to work with classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read all, then write all, never mix. this causes a repaint. an excellent article on this exact issue : 
[wilsonpage.co.uk/preventing-layout-thrashing](http://wilsonpage.co.uk/preventing-layout-thrashing)

Regarding custom attributes, you can add a lot, it doesn't hurt performance as far as I know. their value is only `text`, but you can use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` to decode and encode arrays or objects to be stored in a custom attribute;

Personally I like the semantics of custom attributes and how they expand a DOM element in terms of additional information. It's a better linking between data and DOM for very basic things. For example, creating a link that should open some modal window. you can put on the link itself, in a data attribute, additional information regarding the modal window that should be opened from this link, right on top of the link which triggers that window. it's very handy, and has plenty of uses.

Comment: sorry i didn't get the read all then write all part, can you elaborate a bit more or maybe give me an example?

Comment: There is an example in the article (link in my answer) he explains it in details. also, there is good talk in the post's comments. I could copy his text, but that would be stealing :)

Comment: +1 for the article, it has very interesting stuff but it's not very relevant to my question though.. i just wanted to know if it would be better access attributes directly or use `set/getAttribute` methods

Comment: in that case, it's better to access them in the way the DOM was designed. for class attributes, you have `className` and there is no need to use `set/getAttribute`. for links, you should use `element.href` instead of `element.getAttribute('href'), and so on. you ONLY use `set/getAttribute` when there is no other alternative. the DOM was designed this way.